# c# BinaryFormatter replacement

Tags: c#, .net, binaryformatter

Currently i'm using BinaryFormatter to serialize my objects (which are string[] and byte[])

BinaryFormatter has security vulnerabilities when  method.
the Deserialize method can be used as a vector for attackers to perform DoS attacks against consuming apps.

There is a option to add serializationbinder to BinaryFormatter and implement the method to BindToType where we can limit what types are allowed to be deserialized.

I'm looking for BinaryFormatter  alternative to serialize and Deserialize the objects in my code.

````
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string[] cars = { "Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda" };

      var item = new Item
      {
        Name = "Orange"
      };

      var bytes = SerializeData(item);      
      var deserializedData = DeserializeData(bytes);
    }

    private static byte[] SerializeData(object obj)
    {
      var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
      {
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, obj);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
      }
    }
    private static object DeserializeData(byte[] bytes)
    {
      var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter
      {
        Binder = new TestSerializationBinder()
      };

      using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
    }
  }
  [Serializable]
  public class Item
  {
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
      get { return _name; }
      set { _name = value; }
    }
  }
  public class TestSerializationBinder : SerializationBinder
  {
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
      if (typeName.Equals("TestBinder.Item"))
        return typeof(Item);
      if (typeName.Equals("System.String[]"))
        return typeof(string[]);
      return null;
    }
  }
}bina```
````

Comment: Json is the most popular format, see system.text.json or newtonsoft.json. Xml if you are old school. I usually use protobuf .net for binary serialization. There are *plenty* of tutorials and guides how to use json serialization if you search around.

Comment: You can try [this one](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#binary-serialization) (disclaimer: written by me). Please note though that _every_ polymorphic general serializer (including polymorphic JSON/XML serializers) can be target of security attacks. The threat can be only reduced by natively supporting many types (and by other safe mode mechanisms) so their deserialization doesn't involve type parsing and assembly loading. See the [docs](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/T_KGySoft_Serialization_Binary_BinarySerializationFormatter.htm) for details.

Comment: If _size matters_ you can take a look at https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net. You define a type schema, generate the types from it for different languages and the data can be serialized/deserialized.

Answer (score 1):

For string arrays, if you need to preserve exact binary compatibility with `BinaryFormatter`, I wrote a manual replacement that produces the exact same bytes. I imagine it wouldn't be too hard to tune it for other arrays. I had to reverse engineer how `BinaryFormatter` works and debug how it writes bytes to the stream.

```cs
public class StringArrayBinaryFormatter
{
    public static byte[] Serialize(string[] array)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        Serialize(stream, array);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }

    public static void Serialize(Stream stream, string[] array)
    {
        var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream);
        Serialize(binaryWriter, array);
    }

    private static byte[] header = new byte[] 
    {
        0x00, // binaryHeaderEnum
        0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // topId 1
        0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, // headerId -1
        0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // binaryFormatterMajorVersion 1
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // binaryFormatterMinorVersion 0
    };

    public static void Serialize(BinaryWriter writer, string[] array)
    {
        int objectId = 1;

        writer.Write(header);

        writer.Write((byte)0x11); // BinaryHeaderEnum.ArraySingleString
        writer.Write(objectId++);
        writer.Write(array.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            writer.Write((byte)0x06); // WriteKnownValueClass WriteString
            writer.Write(objectId++);
            writer.Write(array[i]);
        }

        writer.Write((byte)0x0b);
    }

    public static string[] Deserialize(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        return Deserialize(stream);
    }

    public static string[] Deserialize(Stream stream)
    {
        var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        return Deserialize(reader);
    }

    public static string[] Deserialize(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 17 + 1 + 4; i++)
        {
            reader.ReadByte();
        }

        int length = reader.ReadInt32();
        string[] array = new string[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            reader.ReadByte(); // 0x06
            reader.ReadInt32(); // object id
            string str = reader.ReadString();
            array[i] = str;
        }

        reader.ReadByte();

        return array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the `JsonSerializer` in `System.Text.Json`. It might seem a bit confusing to have binary serialization in a namespace that seems to focus on json but it is what it is. This namespace has been available since around .net core 3 and is hopefully available to you as well.

To serialize any object to a byte[]

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(requestBody);
```

To deserialize this byte[] back to an object

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
var originalObject = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<HttpRequest>(ms);
```

If this is not the case Newtonsoft also has similar ways of serializing to byte[]